# No dependency injection possible in a CodecProvider with MongoDB Panache?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I can handle the creation of a custom MongoDB codec provider as described in the [official documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#simplifying-mongodb-client-usage-using-bson-codec), but is it possible to get dependency injection in a CodecProvider as below ?

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {

    @Inject
    HistoryService historyService;

    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        if(History.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
            return new HistoryCodec(historyService.getSchema());
        return null;
    }
}
```

If not, how would you implement an application-aware codec within Quarkus ?

Damien

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible and I don't think we will support it.

The purpose of a MongoDB Codec is to serialize an object to the MongoDB Database, it's not a CDI bean it's just a POJO.

It's the same kind of classes that a Jackson or JSON-B serializer/deserializer and those are not CDI beans either.

If you want to perform some mapping stage (this is what your code seems to do), you should do it on your service layer before persisting the object to MongoDB.

A Codec is just a class that handles how the attribute of an object (think Java Bean for example) are mapped to a BSON Document. There should not be any complex computation on it (imagine someone will call a database from a Codec !).